# How to stop some of the stream in flatmap

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

i am developing a file downloader and i am building my stream roughly like this

```
someobservable          ----------------------------  this stream can generate 1000 of                                                                                     
                                                         downloadable urls
   .flatmap(urltodownload -> {
           downloadStream(value); ---------------------  this steam can pause resume and 
                                                         maybe cancel
   }.observeOn(AndroidScheduler.mainthread())
   .subcribe();
```

how can i pause or cancel some observable creating in flatmap

Comment: Do you mean stop part of the download tasks or all the tasks?

Comment: yes stop some of the downloadstream in flatmap not all the tasks

Comment: Check out TakeUntil operator. For each downloadStream you can TakeUntil the cancel observable emits an item.

Answer (score 0):

I have a not elegant solution. I use `CombineLast` to `dispose`the tasks' `Disposable` by a stopper `Observable`. See code:

```
package xdean.stackoverflow.rx;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.Single;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
import io.reactivex.subjects.BehaviorSubject;
import io.reactivex.subjects.Subject;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;

import xdean.jex.extra.Pair;

public class Q45540738 {
  static Random random = new Random();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Single<List<Pair<Integer, Disposable>>> tasks = Observable.range(0, 50)
        .map(i -> Pair.of(i, download(i).subscribe()))
        .toList();
    Subject<IntPredicate> stopers = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(i -> true);
    Observable.combineLatest(tasks.toObservable(), stopers, (l, s) -> {
      l.removeIf(p -> {
        if (s.test(p.getLeft()) == false) {
          p.getRight().dispose();
        }
        return p.getRight().isDisposed();
      });
      return l;
    }).subscribe();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    stopers.onNext(i -> i % 2 == 0);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
  }

  static Observable<Integer> download(int id) {
    return Observable.just(random.nextInt(1000) + 500)
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .doOnNext(t -> Thread.sleep(t))
        .doOnDispose(() -> System.err.printf("%d task stoped on %s\n", id, Thread.currentThread()))
        .doOnNext(t -> System.out.printf("%d task done on %s\n", id, Thread.currentThread()));
  }
}
```

And output:

```
0 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-1,5,main]
5 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-6,5,main]
6 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-7,5,main]
2 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-3,5,main]
1 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-2,5,main]
3 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-4,5,main]
4 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-5,5,main]
7 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-8,5,main]
8 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-1,5,main]
9 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
11 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
13 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
14 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-7,5,main]
15 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
17 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
19 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
21 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
23 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
25 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
27 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
29 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
31 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
33 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
35 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
37 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
39 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
41 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
43 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
45 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
47 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
49 task stoped on Thread[main,5,main]
10 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-3,5,main]
16 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-1,5,main]
12 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-5,5,main]
22 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-7,5,main]
24 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-1,5,main]
18 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-3,5,main]
30 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-7,5,main]
20 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-5,5,main]
32 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-1,5,main]
26 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-3,5,main]
40 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-1,5,main]
38 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-7,5,main]
34 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-3,5,main]
28 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-5,5,main]
48 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-1,5,main]
42 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-3,5,main]
46 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-7,5,main]
36 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-5,5,main]
44 task done on Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-5,5,main]
```